Teenage girl caught stealing a book
I'm looking for title of foreign movie (most probably French). The movie was a comedy, in color, came out in 70s or early 80s.
It was about teenage girl caught stealing a book. She bets she can write the classic sex novel. Movie about her coming of age sexually as she tries to seduce the man that caught her. Last scene of snow-clad roof of chalet burning.

Any other detail? You say "foreign" but (in a multinational site like this) what does this mean, non English language?  If so, any idea what language?


Néa (1976)

In Genève, bookseller and publisher Axel Thorpe catches willful,
  rich 16-year old Sibylle Ashby shop lifting.



She brags about her writing, so he challenges her to produce a
  book. She writes an erotic novel that Thorpe publishes
  anonymously, and it becomes a best seller. She also tries to capture
  the love of this 40-year old publisher.


The burning chalet you mentioned in your post:

Browse through some video clips here, here and here. 
The entire movie (in French with English subtitles) can be watched here.
~ Synopsis from TCM; Poster from filmportal.de; Stills used are video screenshots
